# .click() en link roto detiene bucle en puppeteer

Tags: javascript, nodejs, puppeteer

Estoy haciendo una rutina con node y puppeteer para testear una serie de urls que paso en un array. Cada web tiene una galeria que pasa haciendo click sobre un boton `.button--confirm`, el ultimo de esos botones redirige a otra pagina. El caso es que cuando el link está roto, la rutina se detiene, y se queda "congelada" en la pagina de error (lo configuro como `headless: 0` para las pruebas) , y yo quiero que en ese caso siga con la siguiente url del array. 
Esta es la parte importante de mi codigo:

```
for (i = 0; i < misurl.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    await page.goto(misurl[i], { timeout: 2000 })
    const pasos = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.box'))
        return links.length;
    })

    for (var i = 0; i < pasos; i++) {
        const btn = await Promise.race([
            page.waitForSelector('.button--preview'),
            page.waitForSelector('.button--confirm')
        ]);
        await btn.click();
    }

    await page.waitFor(1000)
}
```

He probado a envolver el click en una promesa pero "resuelve" todo el bucle en vez de pasar a la siguiente url. ¿como podria hacerlo? Muchas gracias:

```
for (i = 0; i < misurl.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    await page.goto(misurl[i], { timeout: 2000 })
    const pasos = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.box'))
        return links.length;
    })

    for (var i = 0; i < pasos; i++) {
        const btn = await Promise.race([
            page.waitForSelector('.button--preview'),
            page.waitForSelector('.button--confirm')
        ]);

        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            btn.click();
            page.on('requestfailed', err => { console.log(err);
                reject() });
            resolve()
        });
    }
    await page.waitFor(1000)
}
```

Comment: ¿Con que el bucle se para te refieres a que lanza un error y ya no sigue?

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo: cuando el link está roto, ya no aparecen más botones que pulsar y entonces tu bucle no puede continuar. ¿Puedes entrar más en detalles? ¿Por qué buscas dos botones?

Comment: Era eso, simplemente, al fallar la pagina no habia botones y se detenia la rutina, gracias

Comment: ¿Lo has solucionado? Creo que simplemente te falta un try-catch

Comment: Si, el tema es que seguia esperando un .button cuando la pagina no habia cargado, ahora me surgen otras cosas pero ya las preguntaré :) gracias.

Comment: Entonces pone una respuesta, para no dejar la pregunta coja, si tienes algo de tiempo ;)

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que, por error contando los pasos, cuando la pagina no cargaba, puppeteer seguia esperando un boton para pulsar.